# concatenating aac buffers in python

Tags: python, audio, buffer, aac, m4a

I have two audio buffers in python. In reality, I get the buffers from a client (code is running on server) but to simulate, I create a buffer from a file:

```
buff_1 = open("a.m4a", "rb").read()
buff_2 = open("b.m4a", "rb").read()

buff = buff_2+buff_1


f = open("test.m4a", "wb").write(buff)
```

It turns out that a.m4a contains audio - the sound for letter A - whereas b.m4a contains the sound for letter B.

However, when I play 'test.m4a', I just hear the letter A, but not the letter B.  This does not happen with mp3 format (where I would hear both letters when playing the concatenated file).

**Anyone with experience in aac can suggest how to concatenate two aac buffers?**

Comment: I am not sure, if you should directly write on buffers like that. I would use ffmpeg to concat any files

Comment: right, I did that. But then I have to read from disk, and write the concatenated file to disk. I wonder if there is a way to do everything in memory.

Comment: AAC is broken into audio frames.. extract both sets of frames and join them. Google for "MP4 format specifications" that will tell you how to understand MPEG header data. In the M4A header look for section `STSS` it will tell you bytes position where AAC data begins then check `STSZ` for different sizes (bytes length) to extract. Create a buffer with ADTS header bytes then add current AAC frame bytes, repeat for each audio frame (called sample in M4a / MP4).

Comment: thanks a lot VC, currently checking. When I find the solution I will post it.

Comment: works on flac, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!